# Is there a way for me to talk by webcam with my friends who use Windows?

Tags: webcam

I moved to Ubuntu but my friends are still using Windows. I used to talk to them using [ooVoo](http://www.oovoo.com/) and MSN, both with my webcam, but now I can't. I want to talk to them, but Ubuntu doesn't have ooVoo nor MSN. Is there a social page or application to videochat with my Windows friends?

Comment: Come on guys, don't leave half-finished comments, leave some actual answers for the guy!

Comment: I have emphaty, can I use Google talk with webCam with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about "aMSN" or "emesene", both in the Ubuntu Software Center?

```
sudo apt-get install emesene
```

Comment: can I use the webcam with them? @jaezcurra

Comment: Both should allow the webcam use.

Comment: I don't think aMSN is packaged for Precise or later in the standard repositories at this point.

Answer (score 3):

emesene  is a really good app for using msn on Ubuntu.

You can direcctly download it from the software center by clicking on the button below-

[image]

Comment: Can I use my webcam with it? @Nirmik

Comment: Yes you can use webcam with it